# Error When Calling Own Method

Tags: java, methods

So I just started with Java a few weeks ago and I am trying to teach myself how to make my own methods. I made a program that adds two numbers when I compile the class "ClassTest". Here is the error:

```
H:\Java Things\ClassTest.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
            GetNum(int1, int2);
        ^
  symbol:   method GetNum(int,int)
  location: class ClassTest
1 error

Process completed.
```

Here is the code for **ClassTest**:

```
import LotsOfMethods.*;

public class ClassTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int int1 = 5, int2 = 7;
        GetNum(int1, int2);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for **ExampleMethod**:

```
package LotsOfMethods;

public class ExampleMethod
{
    public static int GetNum(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int result;
        result = num1 + num2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try **import static LotsOfMethods.ExampleMethod.GetNum;** into ClassTest.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's important to recognize how you call a method in Java.  You need to specify the object who will fulfill the method, and the name of the method that you're calling.

When you write:

```
GetNum(int1, int2);
```

You're not specifying an object that will execute GetNum.  Java has some default behavior to handle this case: it tries to resolve the method from the object context surrounding your code.  So Java says, "I can't find a GetNum() method belonging to this ClassTest object," and you get the error:

```
H:\Java Things\ClassTest.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
            GetNum(int1, int2);
```

The method that you want is in the class ExampleMethod.  It is a static method attached to the ExampleMethod class, which means you don't need to instantiate a copy in order to get there.  Instead, you can do:

```
int result = ExampleMethod.GetNum(int1, int2);
```

Classes with static methods provide a sort of namespace around those methods, and so the class itself provides enough data to resolve your method.  If you had a non-static method, you'd need to do something like:

```
ExampleMethod example = new ExampleMethod();
int result = example.GetNum(int1, int 2);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's also standard practice to only begin class names with capital letters and methods with lower case, so a preferred method name would be `ExampleMethod.getNum()` - although naming a class `ExampleMethod` is also a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work! Is there any article that explains the difference between "static" and "non-static"?

Answer (score 0):

You could move the `GetNum()` method into the ClassTest class, or you could change the `GetNum()` call to `ExampleMethod.GetNum()`. Not sure why you have a separate class called 'ExampleMethod'; in general you don't usually need to define a new class to contain the definition each method.